# Do the diagonals of a quadrilateral divide each other in equal ratios?

Tags: geometry

I was solving the following problem when this question popped into my head:

Consider a triangle ABC. The sides AB and AC are extended to points D and E, respectively, such that AD = 3AB and AE = 3AC. Then find the ratio in which one diagonal of BDEC divides the other diagonal.
I have found the answer to this problem. It is 1/3. However, I have been unsuccessful in finding an answer to the question mentioned in the title. Help me understand.

Comment: Consider the [kite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kite_(geometry)).

Comment: You have dealt with the specific case of a isosceles trapezium, where we have parallel lines and hence similar triangles to play with. In the more general case, we don't have that geometric construction, but we can still use angles to calculate side lengths and hence get a ratio (which might not have a "nice" expression to them).